# How to properly make a color detection on click in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, detection, color-picker

I'm tying to make a color detection system where when i click on a image it displays the color i just clicked on. I keep getting an error:

> (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int')

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import webcolors


def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        blue = img[y, x, 0]
        green = img[y, x, 1]
        red = img[y, x, 2]
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        colourcode = str(blue) + ", " + str(green) + ", " + str(red)

        cv2.putText(img, colourcode, (x, y), font, .5, (0, 255, 255), 2)

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

        def closest_colour(requested_colour):
            min_colours = {}
            for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
                r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
                rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
                gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
                bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
                min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
            return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

        def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
            try:
                closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
            except ValueError:
                closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
                actual_name = None
            return actual_name, closest_name

        print(colourcode)
        requested_colour = colourcode
        actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

        print("Actual colour name:", actual_name, ", closest colour name:", closest_name)


img = cv2.imread('070929.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 250,500)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello @Suhail. Your question looks incomplete. What exactly error you keep getting? Did you found any info about it so far?

Comment: (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int') this is the error im getting

Comment: If you update OpenCV and use OpenCV 4+ with the new GUI..it shows you the color you're hovering over in the bottom left corner :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing strings inside:

```
colourcode = str(blue) + ", " + str(green) + ", " + str(red)
```

Consider rewriting your code to pass integers:

```
colourcode2 = (blue, green, red)
```